# Property Inject an Array with Spring.Net

Tags: inversion-of-control, ioc-container, spring.net

I've been using the Spring.Net IoC container and can use it to inject properties that are of type `IList` and even `IList<T>` but I'm a bit stumped as to how to inject a property thats of type `string[]`.

There doesn't seem to be an `<array>` element defined in the XSD's and using `<list> <value> </list>` doesn't work either.

If anyone could post the xml I need to inject using an array for a property it'd be much appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned [here in the documentation](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-type-conversion-builtin) you can inject a string array as a comma delimited string (not sure what the syntax is for escaping actual commas in strings if necessary). In other words your config would look something like this:

```
<object id="MyObject" type="Blah.SomeClass, Blah" >
    <property name="StringArrayProperty" value="abc,def,ghi" />
</object>
```

Manually constructing a `string[]` with the following syntax also works, if you need something more complex (for example if you're looking the individual values up from some other reference rather than hard coding them):

```
<object id="TestStrArr" type="string[]" >
    <constructor-arg value="3" />
    <property name="[0]" value="qwe" />
    <property name="[1]" value="asd" />
    <property name="[2]" value="zxc" />
</object>

<object id="MyObject" type="Blah.SomeClass, Blah" >
    <property name="StringArrayProperty" ref="TestStrArr" />
</object>
```